# Gdalwarp: how to set nodata value after warp?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, nodata

I have source RGBA image here is output of `gdalinfo` :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: src.tif
Size is 780, 670
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GeoTransform =
  31.8166046385, -7.21157770246e-07, 3.4459118553e-06
  59.2400684661, 1.75691451519e-06, 3.7128964013e-07
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  31.8166046,  59.2400685) ( 31d48'59.78"E, 59d14'24.25"N)
Lower Left  (  31.8189134,  59.2403172) ( 31d49' 8.09"E, 59d14'25.14"N)
Upper Right (  31.8160421,  59.2414389) ( 31d48'57.75"E, 59d14'29.18"N)
Lower Right (  31.8183509,  59.2416876) ( 31d49' 6.06"E, 59d14'30.08"N)
Center      (  31.8174778,  59.2408780) ( 31d49' 2.92"E, 59d14'27.16"N)
Band 1 Block=780x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=780x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=780x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
Band 4 Block=780x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  NoData Value=0
```

I want to set `nodata` value after warp to some RGBA value, because seems it setted to `0 0 0 0` as usual transparent value.

As I understand from [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html):

`gdalwarp src.tif dst.tif -dstnodata '255,255,255,255'`

But this is distorts the color and that is not what I'm expecting.

Also how to check what `nodata` value is set on existing .tif image?

Comment: Doesn't your own gdalinfo example just show the nodata values for each channel? I wonder if it makes sense to have both nodata and alpha but maybe it does. How do the distorted colors appear? How do you check the result?

Comment: Need more info on how the color looks strange and what program is being used to make that determination. Setting the alpha channel's nodata to 255 seems like a strange choice. An alpha value of 255 means that pixel __should be entirely opaque__. I suspect that may be causing some of the strange distortion. You can also use `gdal_edit.py` to edit nodata values in place rather than creating a new file. As I understand `gdalwarp` can have some unexpected behavior with RGBA images.